# Getting temporary Cognito user AWS credentials using a key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm faced with a bit of a unique scenario regarding authenticating users in AWS. I'm currently using Cognito, which is working great. But one of the requirements is task scheduling. This means I will automatically run some code in the future, accessing some AWS resources (possibly a long-term schedule). I wish to control which resources can be accessed by a certain task (this will depend on the user who scheduled it). And here lies my problem.

ID or Access tokens are no good as they would expire. I could use the refresh token, but after some time, it expires as well. Also, these solutions seem very hacky and insecure. The only way I could think of is to generate an API key, preferably per scheduled task, which ties to the user that scheduled the task.

I have been investigating API Gateway with custom authorizers, but it seems it only authorizes the access to API endpoints, and not to other resources used by the API. In other words, I'm still left without the authenticated principal. Please correct me if I'm wrong with this.

So, now my main question is, can I somehow authenticate this principal in the same way Cognito can authenticate a user with a username and password, but to do it with a key? The best-case scenario would be to get an authenticated principal with several claims/principal tags and an authenticated role using these principal tags to allow access. Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks so much for any ideas.

Comment: 'and not to other resources used by the API'. - are you looking for [Amazon Verified Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/verified-permissions/)?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about this... on initial inspection, it seems this might be the solution. My main problem wasn't allowing access to resources granularly; I could do it with IAM. My problem was authenticating the principal with just a key. This seems to allow custom auth by my own application, which is perfect. I need to dive deep into this and verify it. Thanks for pointing it out, very helpful and powerful stuff!

Comment: Hmm... Sadly, reading the FAQ, I just found out that Verified Permissions can only support customer application resources, whereas I'm looking to protect AWS resources, which is done solely by IAM. Nevertheless, this is a great find, thanks again for the info!

Comment: ‘just a key’ - API Gateway allows you to create custom API keys. Are you looking to do Cognito + key? In that case, you’re looking for custom Lambda authoriser.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but the problem is to have a Cognito + key, you have to have a Cognito token (I think?), either Access or ID. The problem comes when the scheduler hits the API endpoint in 40 days' time. Then, all the Cognito tokens are expired, and the scheduler doesn't (shouldn't) know the credentials to log back in. I am exploring now Cognito's ability to perform machine-to-machine authentication, which works nicely, but so far doesn't provide me with the ID token, so I haven't accomplished full-lown authorization yet with the default role I can assume.